# INSERT data into a table only if it matches a field in another table

Tags: mysql, database

I have data that i want to import into a mySQL DB but only if there is a matching email address in table two.

```
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUE data_1, email 
   WHERE email *exists in table_2*
```

I am not sure if I am explaining this correctly so if you need more info let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: So it is a _new row_ in `table_1` you want to create if the address exists in `table_2`, rather than an update to an existing row?

Comment: Yes, if there is a matching email insert new row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table1(data_1, email) 
VALUES 
(SELECT data_1,email 
     FROM table_2 
     WHERE table_1.email=table2.email)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUE data_1, email 
WHERE email IN (SELECT email FROM table_2)
```